# Convert columns into rows data with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

my dataset has some information by location for n dates. The CSV looks like

```
Country     year2018     year2019        year2020
          saleA saleB    SaleA SaleB     saleA saleB

USA        22   23       323    32        31    65
china      12   12        2     66        66    78
```

I want my data to be of the form

```
Country   year      saleA saleB 
             
USA       year2018   22    23    
USA       year2019   323   32
USA       year2020   31    65
china     year2018   12    12
.
.
.
```

How can I do it using pandas?

I tried using pd.melt but couldn't figured out.

Comment: `df.set_index('Country').stack(0).reset_index()`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, your input is not a valid CSV nor a valid DataFrame

Comment: @mozway solved the issue with your approach, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe with `set_index` and `stack`:

```
out = (df.set_index('Country')
         .rename_axis(columns=['year', None])
         .stack('year').reset_index())

  Country      year  saleA  saleB
0     USA  year2018     22     23
1     USA  year2019    323     32
2     USA  year2020     31     65
3   China  year2018     12     12
4   China  year2019      2     66
5   China  year2020     66     78
```

Another solution with `melt` and `pivot_table`:

```
>>> out = (df.melt(id_vars='Country', var_name=['year', 'sale'])
             .pivot_table(index=['Country', 'year'], columns='sale', values='value')
             .reset_index())
```